# Getting the Razor templates in a class library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3, plugin-architecture

I got a plugin based architecture (using areas) in my solution which works fine.

The problem is that the plugin projects are class libraries and the Add View wizard is therefore not visible when I right-click on the views folder.

Are there a way to get that wizard on the class library? Or are there another way to get scaffolding in the class library project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Are there a way to get that wizard on the class library?

Yes, in the `.csproj` file of your class library add the following to the first `<PropertyGroup>` node:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Comment: It will also convert the entire project to a WebApp (so that a devserver is started each time I run the project. 20 plugins = 20 dev servers running). Makes it hard to test the actual application.

Comment: @jgauffin, yeap, made a mistake. You should only include 2 Guids. I have updated my answer. Should work now.

Comment: To bring this good answer up-to-date: The "E53..." guid is for MVC3. For e.g. MVC5, use `{349C5851-65DF-11DA-9384-00065B846F21}` - you can see a complete list of projecttypeguids here: http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs. Just put all needed guids there in curly-braces, separated by semicolon.